# Issue in graphstream.Graph class

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am using graphstream to plot graph(with lat-lon) using the org.graphstream.graph library.

```
import org.graphstream.graph.*;
```

Below is the code to display the graph.

```
public static void displayGraph(){
   System.setProperty("gs.ui.renderer","org.graphstream.ui.j2dviewer.J2DGraphRenderer");
   Graph graph = new MultiGraph("Test");
   try{
      graph.read("data/fullGraph2sc.dgs");
   }
   catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
   }

   graph.addAttribute("ui.stylesheet",styleSheet);
   graph.addAttribute("ui.quality");
   graph.addAttribute("ui.antialias");
   graph.display(false);
}
```

To include the necessary ui-files. I have also in pom.xml:

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.graphstream/gs-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.graphstream</groupId>
        <artifactId>gs-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.graphstream/gs-algo -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.graphstream</groupId>
        <artifactId>gs-algo</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.graphstream/gs-ui -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.graphstream</groupId>
        <artifactId>gs-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Issue is when i run this code in Intellij it gives no issues. However, while i try to run using command line it gives the below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/graphstream/graph/Graph
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2531)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2774)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1663)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.graphstream.graph.Graph
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 6 more
```

Now I have two questions to ask:
 1) How can I execute using command line with errors showing full(I ama unable to debug due to ... 6 more; it does not tell exact line where the issue is.)
2) Why am I getting the above error only during command line execution?

Answer (score 0):

1) First things first, locate your `.m2` directory. When maven gets the dependencies specified in the pom, it puts them in a folder called `.m2` located in your `/Users/username` (or similar home dir if you're on windows). That's where the graphstream classes live. For more reference on the `.m2` folder, check out [this Mykong post](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/where-is-maven-local-repository/). To solve the `NoClassDefFoundError`, include the following jars in your classpath:

```
/{.M2_LOCATION}/.m2/repository/org/graphstream/gs-core/1.3/gs-core-1.3.jar
/{.M2_LOCATION}/.m2/repository/org/graphstream/pherd/1.0/pherd-1.0.jar
/{.M2_LOCATION}/.m2/repository/org/graphstream/mbox2/1.0/mbox2-1.0.jar
```

2) The reason it works fine in IntelliJ is that IntelliJ includes these jars (and lots of others, usually) in your classpath automatically. To see what IntelliJ is doing behind the scenes, take a look at the first line of text in the dialog pane that opens when you hit "run" - that's the command line that IntelliJ is using.